# <Functional>: plus<long>() on integers gives unexpected result

Tags: c++, g++

I don’t understand why I do not get the same results in these two cases:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric> // for accumulate
#include <functional> // for plus()
using namespace std;

int main() {
    long long i = (long long)  0xFFFFFFFF + 2;
    cout << i << endl;

    vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(0xFFFFFFFF);
    v.push_back(2);

    long long r = accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0, plus<long long>());
    cout << r << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Anyone any ideas?

**EDIT:** as correctly pointed out below, this is due to the sign bit in int I wasn't counting on. 0x7FFFFFFF would obviously be better for testing. Also, I erroneously expected that the return type of plus() would be the same as for accumulate(), which is not the case: it is based on the [third](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) argument.

Comment: What two different results do you get, and what did you expect?

Comment: Now I see, should have taken 0x7FFFFFFF... sorry, stupid question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two problems here:

1. The number 0xFFFFFFFF won't fit in an `int` (assuming 32-bit `int`s), so the value stored in the vector is actually -1 on most implementations. Using `vector<unsigned int>` or `vector<long long>` should fix this.
2. The type returned by `accumulate` is the type deduced from the third parameter. Since you passed in `0`, this will be `int`. You should pass in `0LL` instead so that it returns `long long`.

This program with both fixes will return the correct result:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric> // for accumulate
#include <functional> // for plus()
using namespace std;

int main() {
    long long i = (long long)  0xFFFFFFFF + 2;
    cout << i << endl;

    vector<long long> v; //or vector<unsigned int>
    v.push_back(0xFFFFFFFF);
    v.push_back(2);

    long long r = accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0LL, plus<long long>());
    cout << r << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Slight nit here, but the value stored need not be `-1`, it's implementation-defined.

Comment: Yes, I assumed 32-bit 2's complement representation.

Answer (score 1):

Because your vector contains type `int` and 0xFFFFFFFF doesn't fit into it. Try to change it to `long long`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric> // for accumulate
#include <functional> // for plus()
using namespace std;

int main() {
    long long i = (long long)  0xFFFFFFFF + 2;
    cout << i << endl;

    vector<long long> v;
    v.push_back(0xFFFFFFFF);
    v.push_back(2);

    long long r = accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0LL, plus<long long>());
    cout << r << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Also, as pointed by interjay, third parameter should have type `long long` since accumulate uses it to deduce resulting type.

Comment: This is correct, but I wanted to sum the integers, without causing wrapping or unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Your `vector` stores type `int` which is probably a 32 bit type. From 4.7/3 we learn:

> If the destination type is signed, the value is unchanged if it can be
>   represented in the destination type (and bit-field width); otherwise,
>   the value is implementation-defined.

In other words, your value `0xFFFFFFFF` can't be represented in the destination signed type so the results are implementation defined. In this case, it most likely took the obvious twos-comp result and stored a `-1` in the vector. Then when you do the `accumulate`, it adds `-1` (because it doesn't change the stored -1) and `2`, resulting in the `1` being printed.

Most likely you wanted to store `long long` in the vector (since you're summing values larger than a 32 bit can hold), and as noted in other answers you would also need to pass `0LL` to accumulate to force it to infer the correct return type.